# Is it possible to Highlight <strong> each word spoken in a sentence with Web Speech API

Tags: html, web, text-to-speech

Looking at the documentation, there seems to be no method of capturing the word about to be spoken, and so being able to **BOLD** the current word, so its easy to follow for children.

REF: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html

This is the code I am using:

```
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();     
u.text = element.innerHTML;
u.lang = 'en-UK';
u.rate = 1;
speechSynthesis.speak(u);
element.innerHTML = "This is a test text sentence.";
```

While reading the text out, I would like each word to be bold, and then normal. i.e.:

> This is a **test** text sentence

Has anyone been able to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I have this code, and it gives me the charIndex of the space of the last word spoken:

```
 u.onboundary = function(event) { console.log(event.charIndex); }
```

Below is what I have so far, still not right, but close:

HTML:

```html
<div id="speak"></div>
```

Javascript:

```js
    var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

    u.text = 'This is a story about Math!';
    u.lang = 'en-UK';
    u.rate = 0.7;
    u.onboundary = function (event) {
        $('#speak').append(u.text.substr(event.charIndex, u.text.indexOf(' ')) + '<br />');
    }
    speechSynthesis.speak(u);
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrAddy/t9k8xtkt/)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using the following code:

`element.innerHTML = "This is a test case"`

```
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var words = element.innerHTML.split(' ');
var a = 0;
 u.text = element.innerHTML;
 u.lang = 'en-UK';
 u.rate = 0.7;
 u.onboundary = function(event) {
 console.log(words);
 element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(words[a], '<strong>' + words[a] + '</strong>');
  a++;       
  }
 speechSynthesis.speak(u);
```

Took all day, but worth it now its done.  Hope it helps others!!

Comment: Some issues to report. First all highlighted words remain highlighted so you lose the focus on the specific word being spoken. Secondly, the voice is out of sync with the highlighting. Thirdly, some words get skipped, apparently randomly. But a good starting place.